# Anchor connection how to set commitment to confirmed?

Tags: anchor, commitment

```
        const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
        provider.opts.commitment = 'confirmed';
        anchor.setProvider(provider);
        console.log('kuki: ' + provider.connection.commitment);
```

Kuki logs commitment as `processed`. How do i set commitment to confirmed to connection then if this doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

You can call the constructor directly:

https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/5a025b949e67bf424a30641028973f00325b8f1e/ts/packages/anchor/src/provider.ts#L61

With proper options:

https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/modules.html#ConfirmOptions

Or pass the `commitment` to each call, most calls accept it as a param.